# ReSharper crashes Visual Studio 2008

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008, resharper

I have VS2008 (with SP1) installed on Windows 7 64-bit with ReSharper 4.5.2 installed. Regardless of whether I am actually using VS or not, but with a project loaded, at semi-regular intervals Visual Studio will crash. If I uninstall ReSharper VS does not crash so clearly it is something to do with ReSharper. It be something to do with the following but have not been able to work out what this means or how to fix it.

In the right hand corner of VS, ReSharper adds it's little round icon to indicate the status of the project. This is obviously hopefully green when all is well and red if the applications has issues. The icon for this project is a grey circle with a blue padlock. If I hold my mouse over this icon the tool-tip says "Cannot load solution-wide analysis cache - cannot not write to the cache directory". Yes, you read and I wrote correctly "cannot *not* write". Whether that is a typo in the error or whether they mean that it can write I do not know.

I feel that this may be the key to the crashing but cannot find any information on this icon or the analysis cache. I have contacted JetBrains support and besides taking a day to return emails they want me to create a new project that causes the error and send it to them. If I can manage the recreate the error then I am probably likely to be able to fix it so this is a pretty useless suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Ever feel like you have spent a decent amount of time investigating an issue and hit every dead end but then as soon as you post, something occurs to you to try that fixes the issue and you feel like a dunce for asking? Me neither.

I do not know if all of this was necessary but it appears to have done the trick. I closed VS and removed ReSharper and all traces of it. We are using SVN so I both removed the folders that ReSharper creates for a project from SVN as well as from my local working copy. I then reinstalled ReSharper, opened VS, opened the project and let ReSharper re-analyse the project. So far so good.

Answer (score 2):

Close VS.

Find the Resharper cache directory, it will be named:

```
_ReSharper.[Your Solution Name]
```

Select all contents inside this folder and get properties (right-click, properties).

Make sure "Read Only" is cleared/disabled.

Click OK.

Reopen VS and your solution. Resharper should now be able to write to the cache.

This can happen sometimes when the cache folder is included in source control, the file/folder attributes will be set to read only and can be left that way when removed from source control. (Which is what happened in my case.)